# changing float property of lineargradient with time in android

Tags: java, android

I want to change the float property of "lineargradient" with time, where the lineargradient is applied on textview(i.e. Animating the gradient), So I created a handler in onCreate() class.
the handler looks like as follows.

```
TextView textDisplay;
TextView textCounter;
Shader shaderGradient;
int counter = 0;
int finalCounter = 0;

final Handler styleHandler = new Handler();
Runnable runStyle = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
    if(counter<=260){  
        textCounter.setText("" + counter);    
        String finalString = textCounter.getText().toString();    
        if(finalString.matches("\\d+")){
            finalCounter = Integer.parseInt(finalString);    
        }
        int x0coordinate = finalCounter - 20;    
        int x1coordinate = x0coordinate + 20;    
        shaderGradient = new LinearGradient(x0coordinate, 0, x1coordinate, 0, new int[] {Color.parseColor("#ff000000"), Color.parseColor("#ffffffff"), Color.parseColor("#ff000000")}, new float[]{0,1,1}, TileMode.CLAMP);    
        textDisplay.getPaint().setShader(shaderGradient);
        counter++;    
    } else{    
        counter = 0;    
    }    
    styleHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);    
    }    
};    
styleHandler.postDelayed(runStyle, 100);
```

The method works, but the animation is seems to be a bit lag as I thought.
So my question is, how to change this code to get a smooth animation?

**Update:** I used both of those codes, but still not get a smooth animation.

Answer (score 0):

i think, set a fps, frame per second, its may be because your thread is running too fast, i.e. counter++ in each frame.

get some sleep. not you obviously :P,
its just add sleep before any increment in counter

```
Thread.sleep(10);
counter++;
```

this will set your animation to 100fps, i.e. 1000/10.  Similarly for 25fps, set Thread.sleep(40); .. try atleast. Hope that works :)

Answer (score 0):

With `postDelayed(this, 100)` you have a **10fps** animation. Usually, smooth animations uses at least **24fps**. So, try changing the delay to `postDelayed(this, 1000/24)` and you'll get 24fps.